# IBM Rhapsody c++ code generation - why always put an active state around your statechart?

Tags: c++, state-machine, rhapsody

I am using IBM Rhapsody 8.2.1 to generate my c++ code project.

In the rhapsody tutorials they tell you to draw a large state box first called "active" and then within that draw the rest of your statechart.

See their tutorial [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSB2MU_8.2.0/com.ibm.rhp.cpp.tutorial.doc/topics/rhp_tu_lesson4_cpp.html)

Also anytime I see a rhapsody statechart example its done in the same way.

but... why?, they never explain why things are done... bad enough that I have to use Rhapsody in the first place (company decision) - but the shear lack of examples/documentation is staggering (not to mention lack of forum activity... dead product or what?)

Anyway, I have been creating diagrams without this mysterious "active" chart with no issues thus far (albeit simple ones). Also this is more in keeping with how I would draw a UML design... I have never come across this active state before.

So if anyone has any information/pointers on this that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the tutorial is wrong.

From a technical point of view the enclosing "Active" State is not needed.
The state chart is theoretically invalid because the "Active" state has no incoming default transition.

A good overview of the available forums/ documentation is provided there:
https://rhapsody.blog/more-info/

Comment: Thanks Frank, that is pretty much what I thought too : )  .. good to know other people have noticed it.... but still its a bit strange that the actual IBM guys are doing this practice ...

Comment: Leave a Comment on the Tutorial, maybe they change it.